# vs-code taking exorbitant amount of CPU

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm consistently having problems with VS-Code taking up tons of CPU:

[image: cpu utilization]

Now maybe this is just what VS-Code needs but what is processing? Is there a way to break this down by extensions? Is there any other thing I should be checking?

---

Note: i have already set `"terminal.integrated.cursorBlinking": false` which at least used to cause perf problems in vs-code [[issue]](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22900)

---

The macOS process explorer shows these VS Code processes:

[image: processes]

this is after I restarted and reduced down to a single session so CPU isn't at the moment a problem ... I'm just showing this as I'd really like to map these "helper" processes to the various extensions but can't find any way to do it.

> on closer examination, it's apparent that the extensions are not 1:1 with helper processes so this mapping is not proving to be super useful yet

Comment: why are people downvoting this?

Comment: In what context? What are your extensions? What do you suspect?

Comment: my question is how does one troubleshoot individual extensions contribution to CPU load ... not which of MY extensions are causing a problem

Comment: How is this a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?pagesize=50

Comment: I run vs code but don't have this problem.  Maybe it is an extension.

Comment: it shows that i'm having CPU problems and that I need help on how I can diagnose/decompose the problem. that's all.

Comment: yes I'm fairly certain it IS an extension but how does one determine which one?

Comment: Trial and error with the process of elimination. Disable until success.